# Comparing performance of `ParallelMap` with pure function

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, parallelization, map, table

Test data are here:

```
q = CloudGet[
   "https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/874e3b18-808a-404a-aaa0-4e3ad1ac4668"];
```

I construct interpolation and an equi-distandly spaced vector.

```
qint = Interpolation[q, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
dt = 0.2;
{tlow, thigh, dt} = {0, 37349, 0.2};
tEqui = Range[tlow, thigh, dt]
```

The following code:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 q1 = 
   ParallelMap[qint[#] &, tEqui, Method -> "CoarsestGrained",
     ProgressReporting -> False];]
AbsoluteTiming[
 q2 = 
   ParallelMap[qint, tEqui, Method -> "CoarsestGrained", 
    ProgressReporting -> False];]
```

Returns

```
(* {12.2255, Null} *)
(* {0.195768, Null} *)
```

To make sure:

```
FullSimplify[q1 == q2]
```

returns

```
(* True *)
```

Then I do:

```
q3 = 
  ParallelTable[qint[t], {t, tlow, thigh, dt}, 
   Method -> "CoarsestGrained", ProgressReporting -> False];
```

and (time is similar to `ParallelMap` with `qint[#] &`) but

```
MinMax[q1 - q3]
(* {-1.99493*10^-16, 1.16229*10^-14} *)
```

The questions:

1. Why is `ParallelMap` so much faster with `qint` than with `qint[#]&`?
2. Why is there a difference between `q1` and `q3`? Is it because of the way the `t` vector is constructed in `Table` vs `Range` which introduces machine epsilon?

Comment: For question 2: Your code does not work. Please ALWAYS copy-paste your code back into a notebook and try to run it before submitting a question. This is basic courtesy for the readers of any forum (i.e., please don't waste other people's time).

Comment: There seems to be no gain from parallelization: as `qint` is listable, we can call `qq= qint[tEqui]` and evaluate the whole list at once in about the same time as your `q2.`.

Comment: @Roman I corrected that slight typo.